# How to check whether AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig exists?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I would like to automate configuring and **reconfiguring** Azure resource manager Network Security Group's inbound and outbound security rules.

So I have to check if a rule is exist then using appropriate

```
Add-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig...
```

or

```
Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig...
```

My guess was:

```
if (Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig... )
```

but this unfortunately throws error **in case** the named rule does not exist yet.

Comment: As a thought to anyone finding this later, you can put `Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig` in a `try` block and `catch` the exception - it is sometimes easier to do that than having a whole block of code.

Comment: Yes that was the backup plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this -

```
$rg = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup
$rules = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $rg 

foreach ($rule in $rules)
{

    if ($rule.name  -like "RDP1")
    {
        "rule exist" 
    } else {
        "rule not exist" 
    }

}
```

Obviously you would swap out the "RDP" for whatever rule name you need. But that will give you a true / false for whether that rule exists in that Security Group.

You could filter the `Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup` to specify the exact Security Group you want to check.

And instead of $rule.Name you could use any other parameter (or multiple) to narrow down the selection (destinationPortRange for instance)

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I get the point and tested it. I have say 4 rules, then it returns false,false,false,false if the pattern does not exist at all, and false, false, false, true if the pattern exist. However using it in an if(...) statements condition is always evaluates to true. It obviously my lack of generic PowerShell knowledge, but I have no idea how to use it in if(...)

Comment: I've created a chatroom! I suspect this could get a little too chatty for comments! - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105550/get-azurermnetworksecurityruleconfig